# wait function in the book of unix network programming?

Tags: c, unix

In chapter 5 in the book [Unix Network Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551) by Stevens et al, there are a server program and a client program as follows:

**server**

```
mysignal(SIGCHLD, sig_child);
for(;;)
{
    connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&ca, &ca_len);

    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        //sleep(60);
        close(listenfd);
        str_echo(connfd);
        close(connfd);
        exit(0);
    }
    close(connfd);
}
```

function sig_child works to handle signal SIGCHLD; the code is as follows:

```
void sig_child(int signo)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int stat;
    static i = 1;
    i++;
    while(1)
    {
        pid = wait(&stat);
        if(pid > 0)
        {
            printf("ith: %d, child %d terminated\n", i, pid);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }   
    //pid = wait(&stat);
    return;
}
```

**client**

```
for(i = 0 ; i < 5; i++)
{
    sockfd[i] = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd[i] < 0)
    {
        perror("create error");
        exit(-1);
    }

    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa.sin_port = htons(5900);

    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &sa.sin_addr) != 1)
        {
                perror("inet_pton error");
                exit(-1);
        }
    connect(sockfd[i], (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof(sa));
}
str_cli(sockfd[0], stdin);
exit(0);
```

As you can see in the source code of the client, the program will establish five connections to the server end, but only one connection is used in the program; after `str_cli` is finished, `exit(0)` is called. And all the connections should be closed, then the five child processes in the server will exit, and SIGCHLD is sent to the parent process, which uses function `sig_child` to handle the SIGCHLD. Then the `while` loop will confirm all the child processes will be waited by parent process correctly. And I test the program for a couple of times; it works well, all the children will be cleaned.

**But in the book, the authors wrote that "wait could not work properly, because function wait may become blocked before all the child processes exit"**. So is the statement right in the book? If it's right, could you please explain it in more detail. (PS: I think `wait` in a `while` statement would properly handle the exit of all the child processes.)

Comment: Which book is that exactly? Author(s)? Title? Publisher? Year? Edition? Page?

Comment: @EJP http://www.unpbook.com/, The third Edition, chapter 5. I read the Chinese version of it, so I don't the exact page in the English version.

Comment: How about the section number then? Chapter? Nearest preceding heading? You have to provide some clue.

Comment: `static i = 1;` is C89 or pre-standard code; C99 or later requires a type (previously inferred to be `int`) — and the initializer should probably be `0` rather than `1`.  Note that `printf()` cannot officially be called safely in a signal handler function.  The loop in `sig_child()` is somewhat rococo; you should probably use `while ((pid = wait(&status)) > 0) { … }`.  This radically simplifies the loop body (which contains just the `printf()`, assuming you continue to flirt with death), reducing 12 lines to 4, or even just 2.

Comment: If you have a loop in `sig_child()` and you have (say) 3 child processes and 1 of them terminates, the loop in the signal handler won't terminate until all 3 children are dead.  You need to use `waitpid()` with `W_NOHANG` instead of `wait()`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, I tried to use wait in a loop, and I use two clients(each establish five connections) to connect to the server, and  the client 1 will firstly close one connection, which will cause one server child process exit, then I use another client 2 to connect to the server, it could successfully establish the connection, the server process is not stuck (there are four server processes still connecting to client 1, but not stuck in wait).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with `wait`, but with signal delivery. The `sig_chld` function in the book doesn't have the `while` loop, it only waits for one child

```
void sig_child(int signo)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int stat;
    pid = wait(&stat);
    printf("child %d terminated\n", pid);
    return;
}
```

When the client exits, all connections are closed and all the children eventually terminate. Now, the first `SIGCHLD` signal is delivered and upon entering the signal handler, the signal is blocked. Any further signal won't be queued and is therefore lost, causing zombie children in the server.

You can fix this by wrapping `wait` in some loop, as you did. Another solution is to ignore `SIGCHLD` explicitly, which is valid when you don't need the exit status of your children.

---

While `wait` in a loop finally waits for all children, it has the drawback, that `wait` blocks, if there are still children running. This means the process is stuck in the signal handler until all children are terminated.

The solution in the book is to use [`waitpid`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html) with option `WNOHANG` in a loop

```
while ((pid = waitpid(-1, &stat, WNOHANG)) > 0)
    printf("child %d terminated\n", pid);
```

This loop waits for all terminated children, but exits as soon as possible, even if there are running children.

---

To reproduce the server hanging in the signal handler, you must do the following

- start server
- start first client
- start second client
- close one of the clients
- start a third client
- enter text in the third client
  You won't get a response

Comment: In chapter 5.10, it did have a while loop, but in the book, it says `wait` in a loop could not do the right job, while `waitpid` in a loop could work well.

Comment: Thank you for your update, I tried to use `wait` in loop, and connect to the server from two clients, but the server end process is not stuck.

Comment: I tried to use wait in a loop, and I use two clients(each establish five connections) to connect to the server, and the client 1 will firstly close one connection, which will cause one server child process exit, then I use another client 2 to connect to the server, it could successfully establish the connection, the server process is not stuck (there are four server processes still connecting to client 1, but not stuck in wait)

Answer (score 0):

My two cents about what author meant with that statement.

SIGCHLD gets raised in following three conditions

1) Child exits
2) Child interrupted
3) Child continued.

In case of 2 and 3 wait will be blocked because child has yet not exited.

Comment: But the block of wait will not affect the result that all the processes will be cleaned by the parent process (this is exactly where I'm confused), because, wait is called in a while manner.

Comment: wait is not called again if it failed. There is a break in the else branch.

Comment: Calling "wait" function will block the parent process if child has not exited. Consider the case where after forking of first child, that child gets suspended and hence parent gets blocked inside SIGCHLD handler. Now it cannot accept any more connection until first child exits. This may not be desirable